# weblogic adds "http://" to a normal URL on POST request (Angular/Springboot)

Tags: angular, spring, weblogic, boot

As the title says here below is an example

this is a normal URL "http:/localhost:8080/"

In the front-end I use a post request.
What I see in console is this.

Error: "http://http:/localhost:8080/"

This is the Error "Http failure response for http://http://172.20.217.199/:7010/wsdl/api/wsdls/GetRealTimeBalance: 0 Unknown Error"

I tried to look at my code and here is the code used in the front.

```
this.http
      .post(
        `http://172.20.217.199:7010/wsdl/api/wsdls/${this.wsdlName.replace(
          'Service',
          ''
        )}`,

        this.filterForm.value,
        {
          headers: headers,
          responseType: 'text',
        }
      )
      .subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
          console.log('hi res');
          console.log(res);
          this.DialogData.status = 'Success';
          this.DialogData.text = res;
          this.openDialog(dialog);
        },
        (err: any) => {
          console.log('hi res');
          console.log(err);
          this.DialogData.status = 'Failure';
          this.DialogData.text = err.error;
          this.openDialog(dialog);
        }
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly where the problem was.
but what I did is this and it worked.

```
let url = 'http://172.20.217.199:7010/wsdl/api/wsdls/'+this.wsdlName?.replace('Service','');
this.http
  .post(
    url,
    this.filterForm.value,
    {
      headers: headers,
      responseType: 'text',
    }
  )
  .subscribe(
    (res: any) => {
      console.log('hi res');
      console.log(res);
      this.DialogData.status = 'Success';
      this.DialogData.text = res;
      this.openDialog(dialog);
    },
    (err: any) => {
      console.log('hi res');
      console.log(err);
      this.DialogData.status = 'Failure';
      this.DialogData.text = err.error;
      this.openDialog(dialog);
    }
  );
```